# how to pass data with quotation(") to a dialog in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Supposed I have the following code:

```
<html:link onclick="jQuery('#add').data('name','${name}').dialog('open');" href="#">
```

And with this, if **${name} = a"b"c**, problem occurs, link was not rendered well.
I have tried to escape the value, serialize but maybe my way is wrong.

Any suggestion how to do this? I have been searching, but i just cant find the answer.

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: It work :) thanks alot.. but any solution when ${name} = </script>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [escape your quotes](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) or take it out of the DOM (which I recommend) by putting a listener on it:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('#add').data('name','${name}').dialog('open');
});
```

Comment: Glad to hear it - I'd really appreciate if you clicked the check mark next to my answer if it worked for you. Thanks!

Comment: but any solution when ${name} = </script>?

Comment: It's the same solution as escaping your quotes. It will escape all your non alphanumeric characters - click the link I provided in my answer and check it out :)

Answer (score 1):

You must escape your data value, such as html entity. See [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp) for more details.

And, are you using Struts 2 Framework? Just use `<s:property>` and it will escape it for you.

If not, use `<c:out>` in jstl, it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

What about not in-lining JavaScript?

Template
`<html:link id="add_name_open_dialog" rel="${name}" href="#">`

JavaScript

```
jQuery("#add_name_open_dialog").click(function(){
  jQuery('#add').data('name', $(this).attr("rel")).dialog('open');
});
```